# How do I enable a greyed out datasheet button?

Tags: ribbon

On my list the datasheet button is greyed out. How do I go about enabling it?

Answer (score 7):

Just on the off chance: You are using Internet Explorer, right?

If not, I'm afraid this is an IE-specific function; as I discovered when trying to pry it open with Chrome's dev tools.

Answer (score 5):

As SPDoctor stated - it sounds like an issue with 64 bit install of Office.
[You cannot view a list in Datasheet view after you install the 64-bit version of Office 2010](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2266203)

Try installing the [2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=7554F536-8C28-4598-9B72-EF94E038C891)

Comment: this is 25 MB installer and resolved my issue in IE9 and after updating to IE10 . actual name in add remove is "Microsoft office 2007 access database engine"

Answer (score 4):

Do you have the Microsoft Office client software (32-bit version) installed on your computer? This is necessary to support this function. You may also need to enable ActiveX controls if this is disabled in your browser.

Comment: I believe I am running office 64 bit. That could be my problem. Will test on a 32 bit machine.

Comment: Yes, you need the 32-bit version of Office. It does not need to be on a 32-bit machine, you can install 32-bit Office on either. Microsoft recommend using the 32-bit version in most cases.

Answer (score 4):

It could also be turned off for the list. Check the List Settings > Advanced Settings, 'Datasheet' section.

Answer (score 1):

If you are you using IE11, To sort out this issue temporarily, try to change the document mode of the browser to 7/8/9/10. It worked for me by doing like this.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the 64-bit issue runs a little deeper. If your Office is 32-bit and IE is 64-bit, it seems to do the same thing. Once both are 32-bit, the datasheet icon becomes active.

Answer (score 0):

It's IE 64-bit! Kills Flash & other things too. It shouldn't have been released in its current state, and I only use the 32-bit version in Windows 7.

Comment: Do you have any online reference of your answer?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue .Please try adding the site to Compatibility View in IE , this might fix your issue.

Comment: Could you add additional details regarding how to do this? This would improve your answer's quality quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a filter(data connection) on the datasheet view from another web part?
If yes I am afraid you cannot display the list view on datasheet view.
The datasheet view does not allow data connections.