# How can I View list in DataSheet view

Tags: list, custom

I am very new in SharePoint. I got a task to display my table data in SharePoint list and provide the Action menu. Inside the action menu there should be a option for "View in DataSheet".

Can any one tell me how can I get "Action->View in DataSheet" option on the left side of list.

If possible then please tell me how can i achieve this.

Thankx

Vijay

Comment: It is very frustrating that MS still has not released a 64bit ActiveX component for viewing Datasheets in Sharepoint.. Seriously MS, it'll take your guys less than a week to write the component... It affects A LOT of users!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/13262/enabling-greyed-out-datasheet-button

Comment: Thankx Is there any way to populate the datasheet with datasource

Answer (score 3):

First, you can see "Datasheet" view in IE only by default. Go to list settings or View combo box and click on "Create View". Select 'Datasheet View', choose it's name and check columns that you want to see. If you want it by default when someone open the list, check "Make this the default view" option and save the view.

Second, there is an issue with Datasheet view together with 64-bit 2010 Office and you need to rewrite one Data connectivity driver, see this link

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=23734

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/iersoy/5973/